# Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to print an excel spreadsheet using VB.NET but I'm getting an error

> Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class

Here is my code,

```
Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

    With application
        .AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
        .Visible = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    'Open as readonly and do not update links
    workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(_fileName, 2, True)

    For Each worksheet In workbook.Worksheets
        worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = _paperSize
    Next

    workbook.PrintOutEx()
    workbook.Close(False)
    application.Quit()

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI

    worksheet = Nothing
    application = Nothing
```

This code works on my development machine, as soon as I deploy to the test server the code fails. There is already a default printer driver installed on the server.

Comment: Does it fail already on the first instance? Or on a specific Worksheet?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  You are using the right enum right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpapersize.aspx

Comment: It fails on the first instance

Comment: Yes, correct enum is used. It is just calculated by another class and is represented by _paperSize

Comment: Please let us know whether the computer has a printer installed, and if so, that printer supports the paper size you're trying to set.

Comment: going of @pcronin suggestion.. here would be the code to check paper sizes supported by your printer:      PrinterSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();            Debug.Print(ps.PrinterName);
                foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize psize in ps.PaperSizes)
                {
                    Debug.Print(psize.PaperName + " " + psize.Height + "x" + psize.Width);
                }

Comment: I can't believe something so simple lends to be so hard. I'm getting the same error when trying to set the paper size.  I'm using C#. Excel.PageSetup setup = worksheet.PageSetup; setup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLedger;

Answer (score 7):

You need to install printer drivers. The PageSetup class of Excel must interact with the printer drivers

I'm having similar issue running related code on Windows 8 operating under Mac Parallels (Virtual Machine). For anyone who are doing Visual Studio deployment on Mac Parallels, here's what I'm doing:

1. Disable Printers sharing between Mac and Windows. Go to Parallels
   (VM) > Configure > Hardware and click Print. Uncheck 'Add all Mac
   printers' and 'Synchronize Default Printer'
2. Install printer's driver on Windows
3. In order to get assigned IP address by the same wireless router
   (if you need to connect to printer wirelessly), you need to set up
   networking as bridged. Go to Parallels
   (VM) > Configure > Hardware > 'Network 1' and choose Networking type as Airport and DHCP server as Auto

Answer (score 2):

The issue at the core is in the ***_paperSize*** constant.  In my case, it was giving the same error on: (forgive c#)

```
worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLedger;
```

depending on the printer, for example the "ledger" size paper may be defined as 11x17 or Tabloid. Find out what the print driver refers to the page sizing and then

**DIDN'T WORK:**

```
excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLedger 

excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaper11x17
```

**WORKED:**

```
excel.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperTabloid
```

I hope this can help anyone having frustrating issues with funny inconsistencies of Microsoft Excel's enums.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmation of XSham's answer from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/291298/you-cannot-use-page-setup-properties-in-excel-if-no-printers-were-inst

> ## Symptoms
>
> When you run a Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications macro that attempts to set or get the page setup properties for any
> sheet in a workbook in Microsoft Excel, you may receive either of the
> following error messages:
>
> Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the x property of the PageSetup
> class Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the x property of the
> PageSetup class
>
> ## Cause
>
> This problem occurs when there are no printer drivers installed on your computer. Excel  cannot set or get page setup properties if no printer drivers are installed.
>
> ## Resolution
>
> To prevent this problem from occurring, install a printer driver on your computer. Use  the Printers option in Control Panel to add and remove printer drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use office automation to change the page size something like this

```
worksheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = WdPaperSize.wdPaperLetter
```

or choose any other paper type from the dropdown list on "WdPaperSize."

hope it will help you a bit.

Comment: If you have a look at the code above this was done for each worksheet