# Why can't Python set the Excel print area on a VM without open RDP connection?

Tags: python, excel, printing, virtual-machine, win32com

I'm trying to use `win32com` to print an Excel sheet. This works fine if I have a remote desktop connection the VM this is running on, but if I'm disconnected, the task fails.

I've hit two related errors:

1) With the print area set in Excel:

- connected to VM: the file prints as expected
- not connected: the file prints but without the print area set, so spills onto multiple pages

2) Print area not set, but PageSetup set using Python

- connected to VM: the file prints as expected
- not connected: the file fails to print with a 1004 error "Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class"

Other questions with this error suggest that the printer drivers are missing, but this isn't the case for me, since it prints fine when I'm connected to the VM via RDP.

Here's my wrapper class for Excel:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pythoncom
import win32com.client

from utils.excel.constants import XLQUALITY_STANDARD
from utils.excel.constants impor

class ExcelApp:
    def __init__(self, is_visible=False):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = is_visible
        self.app = excel

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.app, item)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.app.Quit()

    def open(self, path):
        path = self._regularise_path(path)
        return self.app.Workbooks.Open(path)

    def _regularise_path(self, path):
        path = str(Path(path).absolute())
        if ":\\" not in path:
            path = path.replace(":", ":\\")
        return path

    def close(self, wb, prompt=False):
        wb.Close(prompt)

    def save_as_pdf(
        self,
        wb,
        sheets,
        path,
        quality=XLQUALITY_STANDARD,
        include_doc_properties=False,
        ignore_print_areas=False,
        page_setup=None,
    ):
        page_setup = page_setup or {}
        path = self._regularise_path(path)
        wb.WorkSheets(sheets).Select()
        for prop, val in page_setup.items():
            setattr(wb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup, prop, val)
        wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XLTYPE_PDF, path, quality, include_doc_properties, ignore_print_areas)
```

And the calling code:

```
    page_setup = {"Zoom": False, "FitToPagesTall": 1, "FitToPagesWide": 1, "PaperSize": XLPAPER_TABLOID}
    with ExcelApp() as excel:
        wb = excel.open(src)
        excel.save_as_pdf(wb, sheets, dst, page_setup=page_setup)
```

Comment: Do you have a default printer installed on the VM? And is it a local printer, or are you forwarding your local printer over the RDP connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Possible source of the issue

This problem occurs when there isn't a **default** printer selected on your computer. Excel cannot set or get page setup properties.

[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291298/you-cannot-use-page-setup-properties-in-excel-if-no-printers-were-inst)

#### Possible solution

So, Make sure that the script is running with an account that:

1. Has **at least** one printer set up.
2. Has a default printer set up - this is a must!

#### Related:

- [Unable to set the PaperSize property of the PageSetup class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15572525/426315)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503999/426315
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57613740/426315

Comment: Given that it prints to PDF in all cases, I guess there must be a default printer set up.

Comment: @JamieBull Understood, and yet, for an unknown reason, we must set a default printer.

Comment: thanks so much, it seems to be working. On the settings page for printers & scanners I had to uncheck "Let Windows manage my default printer", and then set the "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer as default